# PHP guestbook app

Tags: php, forms, file, file-io

Working on a simple php form (mini guestbook) it is to write to a text file then, once submitted, the resulting page will display the contents of the text file in table form. Here is my code of `index.php`

```
<?php

echo "Please sign the guest book.";
echo "<form action='guestbook.php' method='POST'>";
echo "Name: <input type='text' name='guest' maxlength='15'><br>";
echo "Date Visted: <input type='text' name='date'><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form><br>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myfile = "/tmp/jbgb.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myfile,'a');
    $guest = $_POST['guest'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    fwrite($fh, "<td>".$guest."<td>".$date."\n");
    fclose($fh);
    $data = NULL;
    }
?>
```

Here is my `guestbook.php`

```
<?php

echo "Jason's Guestbook<br>";
echo "<table border=1>";

$file = fopen("/tmp/jbgb.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($file))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo fgets($file);
    echo "</tr>";
    }
fclose($file);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I have two small issues that I need some help with.

1. (In my `index.php` file) When I put guestbook.php in my form action, the file will not sent the data to the text file. When the form action is blank it will send data just fine.
2. If the `index.php` page is refreshed it will send duplicate data from the last time any data was entered. I need help to clear out the variables once the page is submitted or reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your data isn't being sent through is because you don't have any code in guestbook.php to handle the data.

Change index.php to this:

```
<?php

echo "Please sign the guest book.";
echo "<form action='guestbook.php' method='POST'>";
echo "Name: <input type='text' name='guest' maxlength='15'><br>";
echo "Date Visted: <input type='text' name='date'><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form><br>";

?>
```

And change guestbook.php to this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myfile = "/tmp/jbgb.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myfile,'a');
    $guest = $_POST['guest'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    fwrite($fh, "<td>".$guest."<td>".$date."\n");
    fclose($fh);
    $data = NULL;
}

echo "Jason's Guestbook<br>";
echo "<table border=1>";

$file = fopen("/tmp/jbgb.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($file))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo fgets($file);
    echo "</tr>";
    }
fclose($file);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Now that the data handling is moved to the correct destination, it should work!